# Occasional mdworker crash with new custom importer for some files

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight

My **Spotlight importer** is importing meta-data from a couple hundred of my app's document files.

All is working fine under the Xcode debugger with various files. However, the **mdworker process crashes** twice for the 300+ files when running the importer once it's installed on the system.

The stack trace doesn't help much to indicate the issue (some STL libary location) - Is there any way turning on more debugging information for importers running *in the field* in Spotlight server?
In particular the **name of the file triggering the crash**?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just running the importer under the debugger for pretty much everything (a.k.a. `/Users/`) not just a particular file eventually tracked down the problem files, i.e. in the Xcode scheme using `mdimport` as hosting executable and options

- `-d2` (or d4 or whatever)
- `-g $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyImporter.mdimporter`
- `/Users/`